# Get Header Authorization key in laravel controller?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, authorization

Trying to get the **header authorization key** in controller for making an **API**. Request is making from **fiddler**.

```
$headers = apache_request_headers();
```

And the **$header** contains an array.

```
Array
(
    [User-Agent] => Fiddler
    [Host] => localhost:8000
    [Content-Length] => 102
    [Authorization] => TestKey
)
```

If am trying like this to fetch the **Authorization** , its throwing error.

```
$header['Authorization]
```

**Error** :

```
Undefined index: Authorization
```

Tried many ways to get the authorization, but not working anything. Is there any way to fetch this?

Answer (score 185, accepted):

To get headers from the request you should use the Request class

```
public function yourControllerFunction(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    $header = $request->header('Authorization');

    // do some stuff
}
```

See https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Http/Request.html#method_header

Answer (score 43):

Though it's an old topic, it might be useful for somebody...
In new Laravel versions, it's possible to get bearer Authorization token directly by calling `Illuminate\Http\Request`'s `bearerToken()` method:

```
Auth::viaRequest('costom-token', function (Request $request) {
    $token = $request->bearerToken();
    // ...
});
```

Or directly from a controller:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
    Log::info($request->bearerToken());
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you use a specific package like "[JWT](http://jwt-auth.com/)" or "[sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum)" you can use their own middleware to retrieve user information.

Also, Laravel provides many ways to get the authorization key like :

- `$request->bearerToken();` to get only token without '**Bearer**' word the result will be like `44|9rJp2TWvTTpWy535S1Rq2DF0AEmYbEotwydkYCZ3`.
- `$request->header('Authorization');` to get the full key like `Bearer 44|9rJp2TWvTTpWy535S1Rq2DF0AEmYbEotwydkYCZ3`

P.S. you can use `request()` [shortcut](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-request) instead of using `$request` variable

Answer (score 0):

You can try install the jwt(JSON Web Token Authentication for Laravel & Lumen) http://jwt-auth.com via composer.

And create a middleware that verify if exists yours token key in the header request.

After to install jwt, Your middleware it could be as follows

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use JWTAuth;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException;

class VerifyJWTToken
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        try {
            $user = JWTAuth::toUser($request->header('token'));

        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            if ($e instanceof TokenExpiredException) {
                return response()->json([
                    'error' => 'token_expired',
                    'code' => $e->getStatusCode()
                ], $e->getStatusCode());
            } 
            else if($e instanceof TokenInvalidException){
                return response()->json([
                    'error' => "token_invalid",
                    'code' => $e->getStatusCode()
                ], $e->getStatusCode());
            } 
            else {
                return response()->json([
                    'error' => 'Token is required',
                    'code' => $e->getStatusCode(),

                ], $e->getStatusCode());
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

I used token for example for a header key, but you can name it, as you like.

Then you could use this on any controller

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to get headers in any file or controller with $_SERVER.

```
print_r($_SERVER); // check your header here
```

then, you can simply get your header:

```
$AuthToken = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
```